# ASP.NET Concatenate AppSetting Value with DataBinder Value In Markup Page

Tags: asp.net, markup, appsettings

Is it possible to concatenate AppSetting value in WebConfig with DataBinder value in markup page (i.e. .aspx page - not codebehind)

This does not work:

' NavigateUrl='<%$ AppSettings:NewsPressReleasesDefaultPage %> + <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReleaseDate") %>'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx):

```
NavigateUrl='<%# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewsPressReleasesDefaultPage"] + Eval("ReleaseDate").ToString() %>'>
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Curious - do you know what the difference is with using what I originally had and your suggestion?

Comment: What you used to access `AppSettings` is called expression builder, particularly - `AppSettingsExpressionBuilder`. When aspx or ascx is parsed code file is generated and same ConfigurationManager is used to access app settings. Why you can't use expression builders and databinding expressions together is because such syntax is just not supported.